# Transclude element in Angular is causing issues with duplicate attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive:

```
mod.directive('uiSearchInput', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template:
            '<div class="ui-search-input">' +
                '<i class="i i-search ui-search-input__icon"></i><div ng-transclude class="ui-search-input__field"></div>' +
            '</div>',
        transclude: 'element',
        replace: true
    };
});
```

Which I want to use like so:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search internal tags"
       ui-search-input
       ng:model="tagQuery"
       ng:change="showCandidateTags()">
```

The transclude successfully works, but Angular ends up putting the attributes from my original `input` element on the `root` element of the template *as well as* the transcluded `input` element. See this screenshot:

[image]

Notice how the root `div` and the nested `input` elements both have an `ngModel` set, as well as the other attributes?

This duplication appears to be causing issues in my application. Is it possible to avoid this at all?

Comment: This is expected behavior: template - replace the current element with the contents of the HTML. The replacement process migrates all of the attributes / classes from the old element to the new one.

Comment: The duplication is expected? But it causes problems.

Comment: The sentence is quoted from the official doc, if it's causing you problems, you're probably having a wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment, this is actually an expected result when using template in directive, quoted from angular doc:

> template - replace the current element with the contents of the HTML. The replacement process migrates all of the attributes / classes from the old element to the new one.

One possible way to workaround this behavior is to remove all those unwanted attributes from the containing element in **compile function**:

```
compile: function(tElem, tAttrs) {
    ['ngModel', 'ngChange', 'type', 'placeholder'].forEach(function(name) {
        tElem.removeAttr(tAttrs.$attr[name]);
    });
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/1dh75cOQeaPdofdy2HsR